# Understanding & Deriving Jacobian Determinant Scaling Factor

Tags: math, coordinate-transformation

I have been trying to understand Jacobian Determinant.
I hope someone is able to give me a pointer.

Most material that I found on Internet didn't provide
derivation of Jacobian Determinant.

One such web site is:
http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu
(Which I find quite good, otherwise.)

I spent a lot of time trying to deepen my understanding of 
Jacobian Determinant.

I played with Transformations that define uv-axes and
how integration of a function over a Region/area would work
with the Transformations.

For example, when I started with simple Transformations of:

```
u = ( x - y )/√2
v = ( x + y )/2√2
```

which is uv-axes rotated -45° from Cartesian xy-axes,
and with v-axis at 2 times the scale,
that is, v = 1 maps to 2 units length in xy-coords.

So, I say that uscale = 1, vscale = 2, 
for the above transformations.

With this uv-axes, I can simplify a 10x20 rectangle Region
which is rotated at 45° from x-axis, 
such that the longer dimension points at 45° from x-axis.

With such examples, I begin to develop intuition
how Jacobian Determinant works.

I understand Jacobian Determinant to be a Scaling Factor
to convert area measurement in uv-axes to xy-dimensions.

Area measurement in uv-axes is given simply by formula 
Δu x Δv, where Δu = 10, Δv = 10, because vscale = 2).

Jacobian Determinant Scaling Factor = uscale x vscale
(quite intuitively).

Area in xy-dimensions = Δu x Δv x (uscale x vscale)
  = 10 x 10 x 1 x 2 = 200.

Integration of volume over such a simpler uv Square,
could be easier than over the same xy Region,
appearing at an angle.

With the above initial understanding,
I am trying to work out how Jacobian Determinant is derived.

Deriving from the above Transformations formula:

```
dx/du = √2 / 2
dx/dv = √2
dy/du = -√2 / 2
dy/dv = √2
```

I can also derive from Geometry that:

```
dx/du = uscale cos Θ
dy/du = uscale sin Θ
dx/dv = vscale cos (90° - Θ)
dy/dv = vscale sin (90° - Θ)
```

I could get:

```
areaInXY / areaInUV = uscale x vscale
```

which matches my understanding.

However, Jacobian Determinant formula is:

```
∂(x, y) / ∂(u, v) = ∂x/∂u ∂y/∂v - ∂x/∂v ∂y/∂u
  = uscale * vscale * cos 2Θ
```

This leaves me quite puzzled why I have the extra cos 2Θ factor
which isn't making intuitive sense -- why would the
area Scaling Factor depends on how the rectangle is rotated
and thus how uv-axes are rotated?!

Anybody can see where my reasoning went wrong above?

Comment: Check again your geometry for the transformation from (u,v) to (x,y), there is a minus sign missing. I'd think in `dy/du = -uscale sin Θ`

Comment: @LutzL Thanks for checking. I think I let sin (-45°) encapsulates the minus sign; that was why it was not explicit in the equation.

Comment: @LutzL At first, it looked like I had taken care of the sign properly. But with understanding of how Jacobian Determinant is derived, it became the case that there got to be a sign problem. Indeed, I mishandled a sign in trigonometry conversion dx/dv = vscale * cos 90 - Θ, when Θ is -45°. So, your instinct that it is a sign issue was absolutely right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me try to explain what basically the Jacobian determinant does. This is true in general for smooth functions mapping from R^n to R^n, but for the sake of simplicity, assume we are working on R^2. Let F(x,y) a smooth R^2 to R^2 function. Then we can say that F(x,y) sends the x coordinate to f1(x,y) and the y coordiate to f2(x,y) at point (x,y). Then think about an infinitesimal rectangular area, defined by the points (x,y),(x+dx,y),(x,y+dy) and (x+dx,y+dy). Now, the area of this infinitesimal rectangle is dxdy. What happens to this rectangle when it goes through the F(x,y) transformation? We apply F(x,y) to each of the four coordinates and obtain the following points:

```
A:(x,y)->(f1(x,y),f2(x,y))
B:(x+dx,y) -> (f1(x+dx,y),f2(x+dx,y)) (approx.)= (f1(x,y) + (∂f1/∂x)dx,f2(x,y) + (∂f2/∂x)dx)
C:(x,y+dy) -> (f1(x,y+dy),f2(x,y+dy)) (approx.)= (f1(x,y) + (∂f1/∂y)dy,f2(x,y) + (∂f2/∂y)dy)
D:(x+dx,y+dy) -> (f1(x+dx,y+dy),f2(x+dx,y+dy)) (approx.)=(f1(x,y) + (∂f1/∂x)dx + (∂f1/∂y)dy,f2(x,y) + (∂f2/∂x)dx + (∂f2/∂y)dy)
```

The equalities are approximately equal and exactly hold in the limit where dx and dy goes to 0, they are the best linear approximation to the function F at new points. (We obtain these from the first order parts of the Taylor approximation of the functions f1 and f2).

If we look to the new (approximated) area under the transformation F(x,y), we see the new distance vectors between the transformed points a:

```
B-A:((∂f1/∂x)dx,(∂f2/∂x)dx)
C-A:((∂f1/∂y)dy,(∂f2/∂y)dy)
D-C:((∂f1/∂x)dx,(∂f2/∂x)dx)
D-B:((∂f1/∂y)dy,(∂f2/∂y)dy)
```

As you can see, the newly transformed infinitesimal area is a parallelogram. Let:

```
u=((∂f1/∂x)dx,(∂f2/∂x)dx)
v=((∂f1/∂y)dy,(∂f2/∂y)dy)
```

These vectors constitute the edges of our parallelogram. It can be shown with the help of the cross product between u and v, that the area of the parallelogram is:

```
area^2 = (u1v2 - u2v1)^2 = ((∂f1/∂x)(∂f2/∂y)dxdy - (∂f2/∂x)(∂f1/∂y)dxdy)^2
area^2 = ((∂f1/∂x)(∂f2/∂y) - (∂f2/∂x)(∂f1/∂y))^2 (dxdy)^2
area = |(∂f1/∂x)(∂f2/∂y) - (∂f2/∂x)(∂f1/∂y)|dxdy (dx and dy are positive)
area = |det([∂f1/∂x, ∂f1/∂y],[∂f2/∂x, ∂f2/∂y])|dxdy
```

So, the matrix we are going to take the determinant of is simply the Jacobian matrix. Like I said in the beginning, this derivation can be extended to arbitrary dimensions of n,given the coordinate transformation function F is smooth and the Jacobian matrix is hence invertible, with non-zero determinant.

A good visual explanation of this is given at: http://mathinsight.org/double_integral_change_variables_introduction

Comment: I suppose the formula for area doesn't need to be squared:
area = (u1v2 - u2v1) = ((∂f1/∂x)(∂f2/∂y)dxdy - (∂f2/∂x)(∂f1/∂y)dxdy)

Comment: Thank you very much. You have provided a straight-forward derivation for Jacobian Determinant. The formulas are dense, but easy to understand.